# How to join tables with REPEATED RECORDS

Tags: arrays, join, struct, google-bigquery, records

I'm struggling with joining tables, when using REPEATED RECORD fields on the ON clause. The error i get is:
 `No matching signature for operator = for argument types: ARRAY<STRUCT<experiment INT64>>, INT64. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [6:5]`

My REPEATED RECORD is called `ab_test` and it has 4 fields inside (experiment, group ,name, state)

My Query:

```
SELECT be.type, be.group, be.user.id, be.uid, 
       ARRAY(SELECT STRUCT(ab_test.experiment as experiment , ab_test.group as group, ab_test.name as name, ab_test.state, uid_allocation_timestamp) FROM UNNEST(ab_test) AS ab_test) as ab_test
FROM fiverr-bigquery.dwh.bi_events be
JOIN staging_tables.ab_tests_uid_allocation_history uid_alloc
 ON be.uid = uid_alloc.uid 
AND ***ARRAY(SELECT STRUCT(ab_test.experiment) FROM UNNEST(ab_test) AS ab_test ) = uid_alloc.test_id***
WHERE be._PARTITIONTIME = '2017-04-24 00:00:00'
  AND DATE(created_at)  = DATE('2017-04-24')
  AND ARRAY(SELECT STRUCT(ab_test.experiment) FROM UNNEST(ab_test) AS ab_test ) IS NOT NULL
  AND type = 'order.success'
```

I also tried replacing the second ON clause with:

```
CAST((SELECT experiment FROM UNNEST(ab_test) as experiment ) AS INT64) = uid_alloc.test_id
```

But with no luck (the error i get:`Invalid cast from STRUCT<experiment INT64,`group`INT64, name STRING, ...> to INT64 at [40:10]`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried replacing  ... But with no luck ... Any ideas ?

Below is attempt to mimic your use case  - at least that part of it that responsible for the error you see

If you run below (BigQuery Standard SQL) - you will get exactly same error as in your case

```sql
#dtandardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, [ STRUCT<experiment INT64, grp INT64, name STRING>
    (911, 2, 'a'), (2, 2, 'b'), (3, 2, 'c')] AS ab_test UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, [ STRUCT<experiment INT64, grp INT64, name STRING>
    (11, 3, 'a'), (12, 3, 'b'), (13, 3, 'c')] AS ab_test UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, [ STRUCT<experiment INT64, grp INT64, name STRING>
    (21, 4, 'a'), (911, 4, 'b'), (23, 4, 'c')] AS ab_test 
)
SELECT id 
FROM data
WHERE CAST((SELECT experiment FROM UNNEST(ab_test) AS experiment ) AS INT64) = 911
```

The error will be

```sql
Error: Invalid cast from STRUCT<experiment INT64, grp INT64, name STRING> to INT64 at [12:12]
```

To resolve this  - use below approach

```sql
#dtandardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, [ STRUCT<experiment INT64, grp INT64, name STRING>
    (911, 2, 'a'), (2, 2, 'b'), (3, 2, 'c')] AS ab_test UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, [ STRUCT<experiment INT64, grp INT64, name STRING>
    (11, 3, 'a'), (12, 3, 'b'), (13, 3, 'c')] AS ab_test UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, [ STRUCT<experiment INT64, grp INT64, name STRING>
    (21, 4, 'a'), (911, 4, 'b'), (23, 4, 'c')] AS ab_test 
)
SELECT id 
FROM data
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) 
       FROM UNNEST(ab_test) AS ab_test 
       WHERE ab_test.experiment = 911
     ) > 0
```

No errors now and output will be

```sql
id   
1    
3
```

because those rows have elements of ab_test with experiment = 911

Finally, below is example with test values from JOIN table as in your question

```sql
#dtandardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, [ STRUCT<experiment INT64, grp INT64, name STRING>
    (911, 2, 'a'), (2, 2, 'b'), (3, 2, 'c')] AS ab_test UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, [ STRUCT<experiment INT64, grp INT64, name STRING>
    (11, 3, 'a'), (12, 3, 'b'), (13, 3, 'c')] AS ab_test UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, [ STRUCT<experiment INT64, grp INT64, name STRING>
    (21, 4, 'a'), (911, 4, 'b'), (23, 4, 'c')] AS ab_test 
), 
tests AS (
  SELECT 911 AS test_id UNION ALL
  SELECT 912 AS test_id 
)
SELECT data.id 
FROM data
CROSS JOIN tests
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) 
       FROM UNNEST(ab_test) AS ab_test 
       WHERE ab_test.experiment = tests.test_id
     ) > 0
```

Hope you can apply above to your specific case

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer !

The query seems to run when i use the CROSS JOIN you showed, but its running for 30 mins+ and does not end.

So actually its no a good solution as it is now :( any suggestions ?

Comment: as you asked - i showed you how to join by repeated records. most likely you still not properly applied it! so it is not necessarily `no good solution` but most likely still `no good implementation` of it :o)

Comment: you should show what query you ended up with, that still does not work and most likely you now have some different problem

Comment: btw, I also answered few of your older questions  - check them if still interested :o)

Answer (score 0):

When joinning two tables, if the column is not supplied with the table name, it will return `STRUCT` data type.

To solved this, can you try:

```
select table.column
```